# Solutions to $\sin(e^{x+1})-\sin(e^x)=\operatorname{Si}(e^x)-\operatorname{Si}(e^{x+1})$?

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to solve another question, [How to prove $e^x\left|\int_x^{x+1}\sin(e^t) \,\mathrm d t\right|\le 1.4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573887/how-to-prove-ex-left-int-xx1-sinet-mathrm-d-t-right-le-1-4#comment7350158_3573887) (help on that question is also appreciated). The expression $$\sin(e^{x+1})-\sin(e^x)=\operatorname{Si}(e^x)-\operatorname{Si}(e^{x+1})$$ turned up and now I wonder how I could solve for $x$. Here $\operatorname{Si}(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt$, namely the Sine Integral.

[Here's also Wolfram|Alpha's approximations of the solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28e%5E%28x%2B1%29%29-sin%28e%5Ex%29%3DSi%28e%5Ex%29-Si%28e%5E%28x%2B1%29%29)

Comment: You Can't solve for x.You have a transcendental equation.Only numerically can be solved.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Alright, thank you.